# jest.mock factory not being used

Tags: redux, mocking, jestjs

I am having trouble getting `jest.mock` to work in my project. I am trying to test an async redux action creator (not sure if this is relevant though). I am not getting any errors, but my module is not being mocked and the original function still gets called.

My tests all run fine, it is just the mocking that is not working for me.

File under test:

```js
function setYearGroups() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(
      setDropdownData({
        [TEACHER_LIST]: {
          data: yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers(getState())
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Test file:

```js
import actions from '../dropdown-data-actions';

jest.mock('../../year-groups/year-groups-selectors', () => ({
  selectAllTeachers: jest.fn()
}));

describe('setYearGroups', () => {
  it('dispatches action to set year group dropdown data', () => {
    actions.setYearGroups()(dispatchSpy, getStateSpy);
    // yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers function was not mocked,
    // original function is called
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the factory param of `jest.mock` correctly, if you're not getting any errors then the only thing I can think of would be maybe `year-groups-selector` got imported in a setup file (see the warning toward the bottom of the `jest.mock` section [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options))

Comment: Hmm no my setup file doesn't import any of my project files, just configures enzyme and mocks an external library

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

`dropdown-data-actions.ts`:

```js
import yearGroupsSelectors from './year-groups-selectors';

const SET_DROPDOWN_DATA = 'SET_DROPDOWN_DATA';

export function setDropdownData(data) {
  return { type: SET_DROPDOWN_DATA, payload: { data } };
}
export function setYearGroups() {
  const TEACHER_LIST = 'TEACHER_LIST';
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(
      setDropdownData({
        [TEACHER_LIST]: {
          data: yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers(getState())
        }
      })
    );
  };
}
```

`year-groups-selectors.ts`:

```js
const yearGroupsSelectors = {
  selectAllTeachers(state) {
    return 'real computed data based on state';
  }
};

export default yearGroupsSelectors;
```

`dropdown-data-actions.spec.ts`:

```js
import * as actions from './dropdown-data-actions';
import yearGroupsSelectors from './year-groups-selectors';

jest.mock('./year-groups-selectors', () => ({
  selectAllTeachers: jest.fn()
}));
const initialState = {};

describe('setYearGroups', () => {
  const dispatchSpy = jest.fn();
  const getStateSpy = jest.fn();

  it('dispatches action to set year group dropdown data', () => {
    const mockedData = 'mocked data';
    (yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers as jest.MockedFunction<
      typeof yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers
    >).mockReturnValueOnce(mockedData);

    getStateSpy.mockReturnValueOnce(initialState);

    actions.setYearGroups()(dispatchSpy, getStateSpy);
    expect(dispatchSpy).toBeCalledWith(actions.setDropdownData({ TEACHER_LIST: { data: mockedData } }));
    expect(yearGroupsSelectors.selectAllTeachers).toBeCalledWith(initialState);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/52326039/dropdown-data-actions.spec.ts
  setYearGroups
    ✓ dispatches action to set year group dropdown data (5ms)

--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files                 |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 dropdown-data-actions.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
--------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.602s, estimated 5s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/52326039